# Jackson Json List inside object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am having difficulties transforming a Json String into an Object in java using Jackson.

Model

```
public class MyList {    
   public List<MyObj> ads;
}

public class MyObj {    
   public String id_ad;
}
```

Data:

```
String con = "{\"ads\":[{\"id_ad\":\"20439\"}, {\"id_ad\":\"20449\"}]";
```

Retrieve code:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyList annonces = objectMapper.readValue(con, MyList.class);
```

Error:

```
Erreur dans getAllAds: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: 
Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: {"ads":[{"id_ad":"20439"}, {"id_ad":"20449"}]; line: 1, column: 1])
 at [Source: {"ads":[{"id_ad":"20439"}, {"id_ad":"20449"}]; line: 1, column: 91]
```

Questions:

1. What is wrong?
2. Do I need getter/setter for Jackson or public member should work
   fine?

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is incorrect, it is missing a closing curly bracket (`}`) at the end.

Change from:

```
String con = "{\"ads\":[{\"id_ad\":\"20439\"}, {\"id_ad\":\"20449\"}]";
```

to:

```
String con = "{\"ads\":[{\"id_ad\":\"20439\"}, {\"id_ad\":\"20449\"}]}";
```